# Accessing Blob Name(s) for a Azure Container without Regex

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to access just the Azure Blob's file name. For example if I am currently returning the string `privatecontainer/Text-pc.txt` and I am trying to just access the `Text-pc.txt`. The catch is that each Azure Container has different files within it. I have listed the code that I am using the generate a List of Blobs from a user specified Azure Container.

**MainRun()**

```
 public static void MainRun()
    {
        var userInput = GetContainerNameFromUser();
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"));

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(userInput);

        foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
        {
          Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Parent.Uri.MakeRelativeUri(blobItem.Uri));
         // The line above for-loop will access all the Blobs within a Container
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to just access the `Text-pc.txt` without having to use regex? The reason I want to stay away from regex is that the `for` loop above successfully prints out the file name when there are Virtual Folders/Directories in place. However, on a Container that has Blobs without Virtual Folders/Directories it will print `publiccontainer/Text-pc.txt` i.e.`(<container_name>/File_name)`.

Comment: In case somebody ends up here like me, looking for solution for nodejs/javascript, there is no method for it in the sdk but here is a gist with regex for it: https://gist.github.com/Martinsos/34d962b81b01082a45d90b2af5988097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution could be to cast `blobItem` as `CloudBlob` and use its `Name` property. Something like:

```
        foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
        {
                            Console.WriteLine((blobItem as CloudBlob).Name);
        }
```

Please note that for blobs in virtual folders will print the full path (`virtual-folder-name/file-name`) as that's the name of the blob. If you just want the file name, you may want to apply the solution proposed by Stephen and split the string using `/` delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring as I think it's safe to assume that the blob name won't have a `/` character in it. This way you can just take the substring of everything after the final slash. [`LastIndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) is perfect for this. This is pretty similar to a regex method though.

If that doesn't work you can use the [`Segments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Uri. The last one should be your filename

Two ways of doing this added into your loop below:

```
    foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Parent.Uri.MakeRelativeUri(blobItem.Uri));

      //Segments Method
      Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Uri.Segments.Last());

      //Substring Method
      string filename = blobItem.AbsolutUri.Substring(det.Filename.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
      Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
```

Comment: @jdave When I look at this a second time I'm not 100% sure I read the question correctly in the question. So drop a comment here if this isn't an answer or this needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Linq and

```
var str = "privatecontainer/Text-pc.txt";
var splittedStr = str.Split('/');
var name = splittedStr.Last();
```

You'd probably want to make it a bit more robust.

Answer (score 0):

If your filename doesn't have slashes, which it shouldn't because then there is no way do distinguish between a folder or the filename, then you simply look for the last slash and get the rest of the string:

```
var cleanFileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```